# how to sort the solr autosuggestions by alphabetical order when weight of the suggestion is tie

Tags: solr

I created the Solr SuggestComponent, now it is sorting by weight of the suggestion. In case of same weight suggestions it should be sort by Alphabetical order but it is not sorting by alphabetical order.
please help me any one how to achieve this.

the below is my configuration

```
<searchComponent name="suggestcomponent" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
  <str name="indexPath">suggester_default_dir</str>
  <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
  <str name="field">autosuggest_en_sortabletext</str>
  <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">sortabletext</str>
  <str name="buildOnOptimize">false</str>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
  <str name="contextField">autosuggest_en_text</str>
  <str name="payloadField">autosuggestPayload_en_string</str>
  <str name="weightField">autosuggestWeight_long</str>
  <str name="hl">off</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this. I have the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743827/solr-suggester-blendedinfixlookupfactory-exact-match-problem